# Application registers in Eureka using IP instead of hostname when its Docker container publishes port

Tags: docker, spring-cloud, docker-swarm, spring-cloud-netflix

I dockerize my Spring Boot application and deploy to Docker Swarm.

If I do not publish the port my app exposes, then Eureka client sends the hostname as an address of the instance, like `http://ecf28bdd26c5:8080` - **good**

If I publish the port (using Docker's `--publish` parameter), then it registers with IP, like `http://10.255.0.25:8080` - **bad**

It does so even if I explicitly set `eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=false`.

How can I force  Eureka client to really use hostname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by explicitly setting the hostname `eureka.instance.hostname=${SOME_VAR}` or ignoring certain interfaces:

From the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#ignore-network-interfaces): The following configuration will ignore the "docker0" interface and all interfaces that start with "veth".

```
application.yml
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignoredInterfaces:
        - docker0
        - veth.*
```

You can also force to use only specified network addresses using list of regular expressions:

```
application.yml
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      preferredNetworks:
        - 192.168
        - 10.0
```

Comment: Spencer to the rescue, as always :) Thanks